# how to create textarea in j2me

Tags: java, java-me, midp, lcdui

Below code only showing the textfield, but I want to include textfield and textarea. Need Help

```
form1 = new Form("Mobile"); 
tb2 = new TextField("To: ", "", 30, TextField.ANY);
            TextBox tb3 = new TextBox("Message: ", "", 256, TextField.ANY);
            form1.append(tb2);
           // form1.append(tb3);
            form1.addCommand(submitCommand);
            display.setCurrent(tb3);
            display.setCurrent(form1);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you call *textarea* is an lcdui object `TextBox`; it can not be shown at the same screen as TextField.

If you're interested, refer to ['lcdui' tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/lcdui/info) for more details on why is that (there are links to API reference, tutorials, popular libraries etc).

For the code snippet you posted, first thing that comes to mind would be to just replace TextBox to TextField, like

```
        // ...initialization of Form and tb2
        TextField tb3 = new TextField("Message: ", "", 256, TextField.ANY);
        // above, TextBox has been replaced with TextField
        form1.append(tb3); // show "Message" textfield above "Mobile"
        form1.append(tb2);
        form1.addCommand(submitCommand);
        display.setCurrent(form1);
```

Comment: i've already tried this thing, it is showing textfield, but i want textarea.

Comment: I see. In that case, you also need to find a way to manage UI at two separate screens - with _textarea_ (`TextBox`), there's just no other way

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as TextArea in J2ME. You can show either Form with TextField[s] or TextBox, because TextBox is a Displayable. You can show only one Displayable at a time.

Comment: then, how we can  see textfield and textarea, when we are sending the message to anyone. then we have screen in our mobile, in which we typed number in the textfield and message in the textarea.

Comment: These wiews are built by phone's firmware.
It cannot be done in J2ME.